# Does $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=-\infty $ and $\lim_{x\to b^-}f'(x)=+\infty $

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:]a,b[\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ a continous and derivable function. Suppose that $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)=+\infty.$$

Does $$\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=-\infty \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to b^-}f'(x)=+\infty.$$

**My thinking**

If $f:\mathbb R\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ it's obviously wrong. But here, I have big doubts. The function I would have in mind would be a compression like the picture below, but it looks like it's not derivable en all $]a,b[$. What do you think ? One thing I'm sure it's the limit of the derivative can't be finite, because it would contradict the fact the $\lim_{\pm\infty }f=+\infty $. The only possible thing is that $\lim_{x\to a,b}f'$ doesn't exist.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f(x) = \frac 1x + \sin \frac{1}{x^2}$ is an example where
$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) = +\infty$, but $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$
does not exist.

That follows from
$$
 f(x) \ge \frac 1x -1
$$
and 
$$
 f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{2}{x^3} \sin \frac{1}{x^2}
 = -\frac{1}{x^2} \bigl ( 1 + \frac 2x \sin \frac{1}{x^2} \bigr)
$$ 
which takes arbitrarily large positive and negative values near zero.

Comment: Great. And how can I show that it's impossible to have $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=\ell\in\mathbb R$ ? Formally, if $\ell=\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$, the $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ exist, but I have problem to show it rigorously.

Comment: @MSE: If $\lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)=\ell\in\mathbb R$ then it follows from the mean-value theorem that $f$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $a$ which contradicts $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)=+\infty$. – I *assume* that you can conclude that $\lim_{x\to a^+}f(x)$ exists in that case, but that would be a different question :)